# C# Rotate an image around it's position, relative to the mouse position

Tags: c#, image, rotation, cursor

I'm having some trouble rotating an image on it's own position relative to the position of the mouse position. I'm only able to make the image rotate around it's own point instead rotating on it.

The image below illustrates what I want to do:

[image]

This is my code:

```
Image sprite = Image.FromFile("1.png");
private Point spritePos;

public Enemy(Point Position)
{
    spritePos = Position;
}

public void Render(Graphics dc)
{
    dc.TranslateTransform(spritePos.X, spritePos.Y); //Sets rotation point

    float angle = CalcAngle(Cursor.Position);

    dc.RotateTransform(angle); //Rotates the graphics transform

    dc.DrawImage(sprite, spritePos);

    dc.TranslateTransform(-(spritePos.X), -(spritePos.Y));
}

private float CalcAngle(Point TargetPos)
{
    Point ZeroPoint = spritePos;
    if (TargetPos == ZeroPoint)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    double angle;
    double hypotenuse;

    //Calculates the hypotenuse using Phytagoras(a^2 + b^2 = c^2)
    hypotenuse = Math.Sqrt(                                      //hypotenuse = squared(c^2)
                           Math.Pow((TargetPos.Y), 2) + //a^2  +
                           Math.Pow((TargetPos.X), 2)); //        b^2

    angle = Math.Acos((TargetPos.X) / hypotenuse); //Calculates the angle in radians
    angle = angle * 180 / Math.PI;                          //Converts the radians to degree's

    //If the cursor's y position is negative('above' the player), the returned angle is also negative
    if (TargetPos.Y < 0)
    {
        return -(float)angle;
    }
    else
    {
        return (float)angle;
    }
}
```

Some pointers in the right direction would be appreciate thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right basic idea, but wrong order.

First, you should translate your `dc` to 0,0.  Then rotate, then translate back to the original position.

```
dc.TranslateTransform(-spritePos.X, -spritePos.Y); //Sets rotation point

float angle = CalcAngle(Cursor.Position);

dc.RotateTransform(angle); //Rotates the graphics transform

dc.DrawImage(sprite, spritePos);

dc.TranslateTransform((spritePos.X), (spritePos.Y));
```

Currently you are placing the sprite twice as far away from the origin as it already is, then rotating, then moving it back to the original position.

Comment: Thx for the answer, but it doesn't really solve my problem, it still behaves the same way

Answer (score 1):

You should translate to the middle of the image:

```
dc.TranslateTransform(-spritePos.X / 2, -spritePos.Y / 2);
float angle = CalcAngle(Cursor.Position);

dc.RotateTransform(angle); //Rotates the graphics transform

dc.DrawImage(sprite, spritePos);

dc.TranslateTransform((spritePos.X / 2), (spritePos.Y / 2));
```